# Does $\rvert z \rvert +z= i$ have any solutions?

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

$$z=a+i \ b$$
$$\vert z \rvert = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \\$$
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a+i \ b=i \\$$

\begin{cases}b=1 \\
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a=0 \end{cases}

$$\sqrt{a^2+1}+a=0$$
$$\sqrt{a^2+1}=-a$$
$$a^2+1=a^2 \\ \\$$

The equation has no solution

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Seems correct to me. Since the last terms leads you to an impossible result (1 = 0), that equation has no solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a much easier way to see this. Think of complex numbers as points in the plane. The number $i$ is the point on the $y$ axis one unit from the origin.

We want to find a point $z$ which, translated to the right by a certain amount, moves exactly to $i$. This is because we are adding a positive real number to $z$, and adding a positive real number always translates to the right.

So the point must lie on the horizontal line through $i$. This is your $b=1$ equation.

Now how far does $z$ move to the right? $|z|$ is the distance from $z$ to 0. But this distance is always a little more than the distance from $z$ to $i$ because from $z$ to $i$ is straight along the line but from $z$ to $0$ is the same distance to the right plus one unit down.

So no matter where $z$ is, if we move $z$ rightward by $|z|$ we always move it *too far* to get it exactly to $i$.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are some good answers here, but I'll go ahead and add mine.

If $|z|+z=i$, then because our real parts must cancel and $|z|$ is real, we conclude $\rm{Re}(z)=-|z|$; however, because

$$|z|^2=(\rm{Re}\:z)^2+(\rm{Im}\:z)^2=|z|^2+(\rm{Im}\:z)^2$$

we conclude $\text{Im}(z)=0$. But then $|z|+z=i$ would have zero imaginary part, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

with $$z=a+bi$$ you will get the equation
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a+bi-i=0$$ this is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a+i(b-1)=0$$ from here we get
$$b=1$$
and $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a=0$$
from the second equation we get
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=-a$$
squaring gives 
$$a^2+b^2=a^2$$ substracting $a^2$ gives $$b=0$$
this is a contradiction to $$b=1$$
thus the given equation does not hold